# VMware Workstation does not support nested virtualization on this host. Module 'HV' power on failed. Failed to start the virtual machine

Tags: windows-10, virtualization, vmware-workstation

I am trying to run Windows 10x64 on my VMware Workstation 16 Pro (16.1.1 build-17801498)
with "virtualize Intel VT-x/EPT" checked
(its needed for my assignment) but i keep getting the error :

"VMware Workstation does not support nested virtualization on this host.  Module 'HV' power on failed.  Failed to start the virtual machine."

im doing this for school and am totally lost now.
i was previously using vmware 15.5.x.x with same issues.
so  tried upgrading to VM 16 to no end.

pls help.

I have also enabled virtualization in the BIOS.

[image]

My host system :

OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Home
OS Version:                10.0.19042 N/A Build 19042
Version :                   20H2
OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
System Type:               x64-based PC
Processor(s):              1 Processor(s) Installed.
[01]: Intel64 Family 6 Model 158 Stepping 10 GenuineIntel ~2201 Mhz
BIOS Version:              Razer 01.01, 31/8/2018

Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GHz   2.20 GHz

Ram : 16GB
SSD : 256 GB
Hyper-V Requirements:      A hypervisor has been detected. Features required for Hyper-V will not be displayed.

Comment: Your host operating system is Windows 10.  What operating system is the VM running? You must disable Hyper-V on both the guest and host in order to enable nested virtualization within a VMWare VM

Comment: @Ramhound thank you for the reply. VM is running windows 10 pro Education version.
what i did was disable "Virtualize Intel VT-x/EPT or AMD-V/RVI" in the VM settings.
booted up, and disables Hyper-V within...i guess this is what you mean?
i went back to my VM reenabled "Virtualize Intel VT-x/EPT or AMD-V/RVI" in the VM settings . still didnt work.

Comment: @Ramhound thank you, i finally sorted it .

the "Windows Hypervisor Platform" needed to be unticked in the windows features...
this i had done initially but what i didnt know is that 
"Virtual Machine Platform" needs to be unticked as well.

Simple fix took me 2 days ! :-)

Answer (score 4):

@TMRM give the answer in comment !

Vmware is working fine with Hyper-V features unactivated in Windows Feature but since last update seem to have "Virtual Machine Platform" options to remove too.
Need to uncheck that and restart for get your VM working again !

Comment: Thanks, Nicolas! @TMRM If this is still the correct answer in your opinion, please mark it as "accepted" so that others can find it more easily. Thanks!

Comment: This is not a solution.  This is a work around.